# Numberlink/Flow Game: How to spot NP-Complete problems?

Tags: algorithm, np-complete, np-hard

I was trying to find a way to solve the problem in the famous game Flow. http://moh97.us/flow/

After googling I find out that this is a NP-complete problem. A good solution would make use of heuristics and cuts. How can I spot a NP-complete problem easily? Sometimes when I block, I can't see the obvious solution. When this happens with an NP-complete, it's better to recognise it quickly and move on to the next problem.

Comment: Why give up? Just because a problem is NP-complete does not mean that you can't solve all the instances that they're going to give you.

Comment: Just to make sure - it's not a single instance of the puzzle that is NP-complete, while another instance is easy. It's the problem of solving such a generic puzzle one that is.

Comment: It's not about giving up. I'm learning and training algorithms and there are many problems that are challenging. I would rather solve and ad hoc problem instead of a well know NP-Hard problem.

Comment: Well, OK but the harder the problem, the more you learn from it. If it's a programming competition you're training for, then you see, no one is going to give you unsolvable problems anyway ;)

Comment: Where did you find the reference for NP-completeness?

Comment: @peter.petrov Actually, this just happened. Deadline24 algorithmic competition just finished, and one of the challenges was pretty much "solve this Flow puzzle". The instances were of varied size, from small 10-ish, to large 100-ish. None of over 400 teams solved more than 40% of them within the competition time (five hours).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have an explosion of objects (say objects whose count grows
exponentially based on some parameter or parameters), this should point 
you in the direction that it's an NP-complete problem. When you
have to inspect, check too many objects (combinatorial or others).
Usually these objects are subsets or sub-spaces of some initial
object space. You should build some intuition for this. But as usual, 
the intuition lies sometimes (I've been lied like this by my intuition
on 2-3 occasions).

Then once you suspect some problem is NP-complete, just
Google for it and try finding more information about
the same or about a similar problem.

This is what I do at least and I've been
solving quite a few algorithmic problems
some time ago.

Here is a nice problem which I am pretty sure
is NP-complete but which can be solved through
a genetic algorithm for example.

http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=973

And as Dukeling said, there's no generic way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy generic way of doing this. It basically comes down to reducing some known NP-complete problem to solving this problem, or showing that they are equivalent.

So, learn more about well-known NP-complete problems and get more experience with reducing a problem to solving another problem and identifying equivalent problems.

**Disclaimer:** You just have to be careful of special cases of NP-complete problems - while the generic case of the problem may require exponential time to be solved, these special cases may actually be solvable in polynomial time.